# VBA IE.Document.All

Tags: vba, excel

I'm running a very simple Excel VBA code that goes to a website, and fills in a form (thousands of similar posts out there), however I need the box it's filling out to change based on a cell in my Excel file.

Right now the line of code I'm trying is:

```
IE.Document.All(Worksheets("sheet1").Range("a1")).Value = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("a2")
```

However whenever I try running it, I get a runtime error saying "Object Required". I'm guessing the `IE.Document.All(Worksheets("sheet1").Range("a1"))` part is not how I'm supposed to do it, so I'm hoping someone can provide me with the right way (I'm very new to VBA). The program works fine if I repalce that part with the Name of the box on the form (from inspect element), or it also works if the box A1 just has text in it, however the box I'm trying to pull has a formula that puts together a string of text

Comment: Can you share the URL and/or the html in question? Show more of the code and the replacements that do work.

Comment: `IE.Document.All` accepts the index of the element you want to get, are you sure that your  cell `a1` contains a number and is formatted as a number? if it contains a number then try casting it to Long: `IE.Document.All(Clng(Worksheets("sheet1").Range("a1"))).Value = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("a2")`